# Chrome Extension: Message Passing from popup to DOM results in textbox filled with "undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I have pieced together code for a basic Chrome extension, using message passing, to fill in text fields and combo boxed on a website.  The following code results in the text boxes reading "undefined".  Where am I going wrong?

manifest.json

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "Click to execute",
 "description": "ARM Filler",
 "version": "1.0",
 "icons": {
           "48": "icon.png"
           },
 "permissions": [
                 "tabs", "<all_urls>"
                ],
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
                  },
"content_scripts": [
                      {
                       "matches": ["https://(secure website here)*"],
                       "js": ["popup.js"]
                      }
                    ]
 }
```

myscript.js

```
window.onload=function(){

 document.getElementById('buttonSet').addEventListener('click',function(){

 chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
 for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {user :document.getElementById('txtfn').value,
                                     pass :document.getElementById('txtln').value}, function(response) {
        });
 }
 }); 

 });

 }
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
     document.getElementsByName("firstName")[0].value=request.txtfn;
     document.getElementsByName("lastName")[0].value=request.txtln;

});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <style>
      .container {
        max-height: 1200px;
        min-height: 600px;
        width: 600px;
        border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        border-radius: 2px;
        background: white;
      }
      body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
      }
      #status {
        /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 400px;
      }
      .patient-list {
        max-height: 250px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h3>ARM Applicant Updater</h3>
          <p id="status"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtfn" name="txtfn"><br>
            <label>Last Name</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtln" name="txtln"><br>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonSet" name="update">Update</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/extension.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The goal is to fill in only critical text and combo boxes on a form that has about 150 different inputs by using a simplified popup.  The popup will only contain about 15 of the 150 fields so users don't have to scroll endlessly to find the required fields.

Thanks in advance!
- Matt

Comment: You're sending an object like {user, pass} but reading it as {txtfn, txtln} in popup.js.

Comment: Goodness.   How did I miss that one!  I'll change that up in the morning and pray that it works.  Thanks!